# Disable Mobile Theme in Specific Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile, themes, bbpress

I have been trying to figure out a way to correct BBPress on my website: https://medicforyou.in . I am using Newspaper 7 theme which has two specific php files- bbpress.php and bbpress.php in mobile/bbpress.php. Tried to call php echo to use shortcodes, tried almost everything.

Couldn't really fix forums being server properly. The only solution that seems to work out is disable the mobile theme, but that would slow down the website by 3-5 seconds.

So, m thinking maybe disabling mobile plugin/theme for bbpress can work. Anyone has ideas about it, please suggest. M stuck with launching forums if the functionality is not good.

Forums page: https://medicforyou.in/forums